# How to get items from parsing web page?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, html-parsing

There is a [website](https://rage.mp/masterlist/?query=gun) on which there is a list of game servers. How can I get the data of the top 5 servers in Json format in Python, where they will be specified: 'Server name'(title), 'online'(count).
Parsing website link: https://cdn.rage.mp/master/?query=gun
Website link: https://rage.mp/masterlist/?query=gun
I want to display top 5 server by field "players".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://cdn.rage.mp/master/')

d = sorted(r.json().values(), key=lambda x: x['players'], reverse=True)[0:5]

print(d)
```

```
[{'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | DownTown | gta5rp.com/discord',
  'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'players': 1662,
  'peak': 1716,
  'maxplayers': 5000},
 {'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | VineWood | gta5rp.com/discord',
  'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'players': 1568,
  'peak': 1578,
  'maxplayers': 5000},
 {'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | Eclipse | gta5rp.com/discord',
  'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'players': 1459,
  'peak': 1489,
  'maxplayers': 5000},
 {'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | StrawBerry | gta5rp.com/discord',
  'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'players': 1389,
  'peak': 1397,
  'maxplayers': 5000},
 {'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | Sunrise | gta5rp.com/discord [1.1]',
  'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'players': 1323,
  'peak': 1337,
  'maxplayers': 3500}]
```

Comment: I need to get sort by top 5 biggest field 'players'.

Comment: @МаксимПигидин2 check